# How to make random image from array responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an array with four different images which are randomly picked. Works like a charm.

My question is how to make those images responsive?

```js
// place your images in this array
var random_images_array = ['1.jpg', '2.gif', '3.gif', '4.gif'];

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
  path = path || 'random/'; // default path here
  
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
  var img = imgAr[num];
  var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
  
  document.write(imgStr);
  document.close();
}

getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'random/')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive"? Just so they size to fit, or actually using `srcset` and such?

Comment: Also: `document.write()` bad; I'd recommend having a placeholder `img` tag in your markup, getting that by its ID, and changing its source.

Comment: Hi thank you for your fast reply. Just that the pictures sizes to fit is needed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [great post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/time-saving-css-techniques-to-create-responsive-images-ebb1e84f90d5/)

In short:

```
div img {  height: auto;  width: 100%; }

<div><img src="imgsrc" alt=""></div>
```

Is one way....

Comment: where do i implement this? i tried several things and it just cuts off the image. The javascript thing i copied out is only a smaller part of something

Comment: Do you have a container for you image? If so put it inside like in the edited post.

Comment: <div class="blabla"> <script type="text/javascript">getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'random/')</script></div>  doesnt do anything, many thanks in advance